# Populate Spinner from string array source, with a String ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, xml, spinner

I have created my application by populating spinners within my Java code. I am now trying to convert it to populating my Spinners from my strings.xml file. I have followed a few websites( [example 1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) and [example 2](http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/21-android-tutorial-spinners?showall=1) ), but have not been able to get my code to work.

The main problem with those is that the ArrayAdapter's they use are of type `<CharSequence>`. Can I do this somehow using `<String>` ArrayAdapters?

This is my array in my XML file :

```
<string-array name="anti_pump_ap_mode_array">
    <item>OFF</item>
    <item>Anti-Pump</item>
    <item>Motor Cut...</item>
</string-array>
```

Here is the code I've tried :

```
apModeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.array.anti_pump_ap_mode_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );

apModeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.anti_pump_ap_mode_array );

apModeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.anti_pump_ap_mode_array );
```

Of course the last one gives me an error, but the first two just do not populate my spinner. When I run the application the Spinner is just empty.

Comment: what are the error in logcat?

Comment: One minute let me run it again sorry.

Comment: @Akshay Oh, wait there is no LogCat error. The first 2 ways of creating the ArrayAdapter create an empty spinner, while the third way just gives me an error and won't let me run the program.

Comment: haha then why won't it work??? I thought the same thing, but clearly theres some kind of difference that makes it not work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use below way, interchange array id and layout id. Textarray resource id is second parameter

```
apModeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.anti_pump_ap_mode_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  );
```

Edit:
For the first way to work. get the string array from resources

```
Resources res = getResources();
apModeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, res.getStringArray(R.array.anti_pump_ap_mode_array) );
```

Answer (score 2):

`CharSequence` is an interface that `String` implements, so even though the API `createFromResource()` returns the interface type, it is still filled with your `String` array.  If you truly needed to access the results as a String later, you could cast the accessor.  However, most Android UI methods take `CharSequence` as input also.

In addition, the parameters are reversed.  It should look like this:

```
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.anti_pump_ap_mode_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
```

Comment: I was hoping this wasn't the answer. I would like to figure out a way to do it with a `<String>` adapter, as I have a LOT of Spinners already set up with those. I would need to cast a lot of things. Are you sure this is the only way?