# Create a search box in android

Tags: android, search, arraylist

I need to create a `search box` in android where it check the data from `arraylist` if it is in there it will return to that page.

code:

```
 String[] text = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
   "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };

edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
  {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
   {

   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
    int count, int after)
   {

   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
    int before, int count)
   {

    textlength = edittext.getText().length();
    text_sort.clear();
    image_sort.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
     if (textlength <= text[i].length())
     {
      if (edittext.getText().toString().
   equalsIgnoreCase((String) text[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
      {

      }
     }
    }
```

i got the above code for `search functionality` But i need when user will `search any keyword` it will check from the `array list` ,if it is in there it will return to that page else it will show `no data found`!

Answer (score 0):

insted of EditText use `AutoCompleteTextView`

[AutoCompleteTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804805/android-actionbar-searchview-as-autocomplete/15877582#15877582) : here i have used that in ActionBar. you can also use that in activity. Its very simple.

for more detail check this [artical](https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android) and [code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

for Actionbar you have to add **android-suport-v4.jar** file in your code..

Comment: @thanks Dhaval Sodha Parmar whether it will support every version of android device!!

Comment: Dhaval Sodha Parmar thanks can i create custom listview here!!

Comment: @ Dhaval Sodha Parmar custom listview using adapter

Comment: @priya2134412: yes... http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-autocompletetextview-to-display-images-and-text-in-the-suggestion-list-using-simpleadapter-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the android functionality which is [Usage of SearchView in an ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

There is also its compatibility provided [Collapsable SearchView](http://johnkil.github.io/Android-CollapsibleSearchMenu/)

Below is the way you can implement the searching from the `ArrayList` try out:

> ```
>   public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity
>    {
>      private ArrayAdapter<String> m_arrayAdapter;
>      private SearchView m_searchView;
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle p_savedInstanceState)
> {
>     super.onCreate(p_savedInstanceState);
>     // setContentView(R.layout.search);
>     m_arrayAdapter =
>             new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, m_items);
>     setListAdapter(m_arrayAdapter);
> }
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu)
> {
>     // MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
>     // inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
>     m_searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
>     m_searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);//Set the submit button on search view.
>     // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
>     // SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
>     // SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
>     // searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
>     m_searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener()
>     {
>         @Override
>         public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String p_query)
>         {
>             m_arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(p_query);
>             return true;
>         }
>         @Override
>         public boolean onQueryTextChange(String p_newText)
>         {
>             m_arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(p_newText);
>             return false;
>         }
>     });
>     return true;
> };
> String[] m_items = new String[] { "China", "India", "United States", "Indonesia", "Brazil",
>         "Pakistan", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh", "Russia", "Japan", "Mexico", "Philippines",
>         "Vietnam", "Ethiopia", "Egypt", "Germany", "Iran", "Turkey",
>         "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Thailand", "France", "United Kingdom", "Italy",
>         "South Africa", "Myanmar", "South Korea", "Colombia", "Spain", "Ukraine", "Tanzania",
>         "Kenya", "Argentina", "Poland", "Algeria", "Canada" };
>   }
> ```

Comment: thanks but what i want is i don't want to display any listview while search,once the user type the keyword it will search from the arraylist whether the keyword is present or not ! if is there it will return to that page else it will display as no data found! am i clear!!

Comment: If you do not want the listview then simply you can remove the code of the Listview directly get the results directly from the ArrayList.