# how to combine edit text with spinner

Tags: android, authentication, android-edittext

I am writing simple login activity.
I have login edit text and password edit text.
I am kepping login and pasword via sharedpreferences.
I want to make login field to rember previous logins (eg "aaa" and "aab") so when you type in edit text it give you some options and you can choose them to outo complite it. 
How it can be done?

Comment: use auto complete textview. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15877582/1168654

Comment: you answer was first with link to proper example, i'd like to rate your comment  as solution, please post it as answer

Comment: no need to do that just give +1 on that ans... thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use AutoCompleteTextView instead of simple EditText
check dev link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

also check this link for detail http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example

Answer (score 1):

You can use AutoCompleteTextView for the login field, and use a suitable adapter to display the values.  If you are remembering the previous login IDs, then, you can store them in SQLite DB and use CursorAdapter to populate the auto complete text view.