# getting error while adding spinner to the right of action bar

Tags: android

getting the following error 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams to android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActionBar().getThemedContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            final View spinnerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_spinner, null);
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) spinnerView.findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Location, R.layout.spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

//          spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
//
//              @Override
//              public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//                  // Do whatever you want with your selected item. You can get it as: parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
//              }
//
//              @Override
//              public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
//          });

            getActionBar().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loc));//set your actionbar logo
            getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE );

            LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT; // set your layout's gravity to 'right'
            getActionBar().setCustomView(spinnerView, layoutParams); //place your layout on the actionbar
```

i am getting error at `new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);`

please help...i am not able to solve the error as i am new to android

Comment: you have imported wrong line change `import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams` to  `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams`

Comment: The method setCustomView(android.view.View, android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams) in the type ActionBar is not applicable for the arguments (android.view.View, android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams) now i am getting this error

Comment: thanks i got it ..can u please tell me how to add the value of a variable ny default to the spinner on page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using support jar then change

```
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams
```

to

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams
```

and if not then vice-versa.

Comment: now i am getting this error The method setCustomView(android.view.View, android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams) in the type ActionBar is not applicable for the arguments (android.view.View, android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams)

Comment: You need to do as suggested in my answer in whole of your application. Changing it at one place won't work because passing argument is of one type and receiving is of another type. Do you need to use support jar in your application for backward compatibility?

Comment: thanks i got it ..can u please tell me how to add the value of a variable ny default to the spinner on page load

Comment: What is your android:spinnerMode in xml file?

Comment: can you please tell me how to add a autocomplete text view in place of spinner in the action bar

Comment: If android:spinnerMode is "dialog" than do this android:prompt="value" and if its "dropdown" then do this `spinner.setSelection(index)` where index is the position of item to be set as default in the adapter

Comment: thanks but can you tell me how to add autocompletetext view in place of spinner

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804805/android-actionbar-searchview-as-autocomplete

Comment: thanku soo much...how to add a initial default value to this textview can u please help me out

Comment: Post a new question for this with details of what have you dont so far because this is going to be off topic now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import correct `LayoutParams`

Remove :

```
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams
```

Add :

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams
```

If you still get the exception, do Vice-versa

Comment: The method setCustomView(android.view.View, android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams) in the type ActionBar is not applicable for the arguments (android.view.View, android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams)...now i am getting this error

Comment: are you using support lib ? then do vice-versa and check

Comment: thanks i got it ..can u please tell me how to add the value of a variable ny default to the spinner on page load

Comment: can you please tell me how to add a autocomplete text view in place of spinner in the action bar