# What is the best way to implement search in Android?

Tags: java, android, json, android-search

## Scenario

I needed to introduce a `search` or `filter` in my android application on the basis of some `Tags`. I have a `Json` response coming from some `Retrofit` calls in a `Staggered Grid` view.

## Questions

- What would be good approach to do it? Instant Search? If yes, then How can i achieve it?
- I am fetching data in `Json` and saving it into `Model` class. Can I take help from `Model` class to implement Search?
- How can retrofit help me in searching?
- Any other concerns?

Any help would be appreciable :)

## Edit-1

Elaborating more:

- I do have a `Json` response coming from `Retrofit` request.
- Sample of `json`:

  ```
  {"Value":2,"tags":["workout","game"]}
  {"Value":2,"tags":["game","person"]}
  ```
- There are a lot of data coming from the `Json` which I am not pasting here. I am loading above `Json` in `Recycler Staggered Grid View`.
- I do have a Search bar where user will put multiple `Tags` like `game, Person`.
- This search will fetch `Values` associated with given `Tags` in search box.

Comment: @Neha I am using `Staggered Grid View` through Recycler View

Comment: @Neha Have you looked at `Edit-1` section?

Comment: I think you just need a classic filter, looping through your Model list and select items based on their tag.

Comment: yes i have seen that...u jus have to apply filter on ur model class and reset your layout as per the new data..i dont understand where lies the problem..if u r already doing that

Answer (score 0):

Instant serach can be implemented with the help of AutoCompleteTextView.

you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804805/android-action-bar-searchview-as-autocomplete) and [this](http://www.drzon.net/how-to-create-a-clearable-autocomplete-dropdown-with-autocompletetextview/) links-

Maybe you can save your tags in database and you can pop out tags as a List and attach this to adapter and rest of the work AutoCompleteTextView will take care of.

Or you can use SearchView. You can customize it also according to your needs.

Comment: Isn't  `AutoCompleteTextView` is completely different approach from Search? AutoCompleteTextView will help me when User don't know the exact name of tags. But In my case User already knew about the tags what they have to fetch other data associated to these tags

Comment: Could you please ellaborate what kind of search feature you want in your app?

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use Fragment.Fragment makes easy to your requirement.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how Fragment can help here?