# How to implement AutoCompleteTextView within onQueryTextChange function of SearchView in actionbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to implement an AutoCompleteTextView within the onQueryTextChange function of searchView, so that I get a suggestion list when I start typing in the search. How can I implement it?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);

    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, buildings);
    final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
        {

            AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            textView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

The `Layout` file, named `activity_search.xml`.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nested_parentframe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <!-- HERE IS WHERE YOUR OTHER VIEWS SHOULD GO -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/nested_toolbar_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:cardElevation="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#ffffff">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/nested_toolbar_2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="56dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/cardsList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the `Menu` where `SearchView` is placed, named `search_menu.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_menu_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_grey"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="yourpackage.ArrayAdapterSearchView"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:title="Search" />
</menu>
```

Here is a custom `ArrayAdapter` for the `SearchView`.

```
public class ArrayAdapterSearchView extends SearchView {

    private SearchView.SearchAutoComplete mSearchAutoComplete;

    public ArrayAdapterSearchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    public ArrayAdapterSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        mSearchAutoComplete = (SearchAutoComplete) findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        this.setAdapter(null);
        this.setOnItemClickListener(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSuggestionsAdapter(CursorAdapter adapter) {
        // don't let anyone touch this
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mSearchAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
    }

    public void setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<?> adapter) {
        mSearchAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        mSearchAutoComplete.setText(text);
    }

    public void setSelection(int position){
        mSearchAutoComplete.setSelection(position);
    }

    public String getText(){
        return mSearchAutoComplete.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Here is the RecyclerView list item layout, named `card_item.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemNametxt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text=""
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Inside your Custom `Adapter` write a function like this.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter .CustomRecyclerHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = null, stringArrayList;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = items;
        this.stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.stringArrayList.addAll(items);
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.CustomRecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);

        return new CustomRecyclerHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.CustomRecyclerHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.item.setText(arrayList.get(position).toString());
    }

    public class CustomRecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        protected TextView item;

        public CustomRecyclerHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            item = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemNametxt);

            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onItemClick(item.getText().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.arrayList.size();
    }

    public void filter(String filterString) {
        filterString = filterString.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        arrayList.clear();//Your list of items
        if(filterString.length() == 0) {
            arrayList.addAll(stringArrayList);
            //stringArrayList - 2nd list of items
        }
        else {
            for(String item : stringArrayList){
                if(item.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(filterString)) {
                    arrayList.add(item );
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        public void onItemClick(String item);
    }
}
```

Finally the `Activity`.
**EDITED**

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayAdapterSearchView searchView;
    private LinearLayout recycleLayout;
    private ArrayList<String> stringList;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;
    private Toolbar mToolbar1, mToolbar2;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        mToolbar1 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nested_toolbar_1);
        mToolbar2 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nested_toolbar_2);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.nested_parentframe);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar2);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search");
        mToolbar1.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_action_overflow);

        mToolbar2.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.tertiary_text_light));

        recycleLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewLayout);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardsList);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        String[] strArray = new String[]{"Item One", "Item Two", "Item Three", "Item Four", "Item Five"};
        //This is your String array
        for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
            stringList.add(strArray[i]);
        }

        if(!stringList.isEmpty()){
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, stringList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            recycleLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new CustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(String item) {
                    searchView.setQuery(item, false);
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            recycleLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }       

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_menu_item);

        searchView = (ArrayAdapterSearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.LEFT));

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                if (query.length() != 0) {
                    if (null != adapter) {
                        adapter.filter(query.toString());//This will filter the RecyclerView
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String length = searchView.getText();
                searchView.setSelection(length.length());
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please give me the entire code? As in from Main Activity.java and the layout files? It would be very helpful

Comment: Just to let you know, I am not using any listView for searching the items. I've created a string array in the MainActivity.java

Comment: I have provided the code for searching through a ListView. I can give you a full code if you like. But ss per your last comment, what I understood is you don't want a ListView, but an AutoComplete Adapter to set to the ActionBat Menu.

Comment: Yes I want an AutoComplete adapter. Can you please provide me with the full code for that?

Comment: I suggest you to follow this example.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804805/android-action-bar-searchview-as-autocomplete

Comment: Thank you! But I am specifically looking at creating a Search Bar with autoComplete feature in it. I've already created something similar to what you've suggested. It has an autoCompleteTextView in it, which is not what I want. I hope you understand what I mean. Please suggest me a solution

Comment: Sure. I have this workaround which SearchView acts as an AutoCompleteTextView but it uses a RecyclerView to display the suggestions. I could provide you that I you like.

Comment: Sure. That would be really helpful. Please do provide me with the entire code

Comment: And also, just to let you know, I am not using a ListView. I've declared a string array in my MainActivity.java.

Comment: No problem. You can use a String array for populating the ListView.

Comment: Oh okay. I will go through it. Please send the code

Comment: I have edited the answer and let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: changed PlaceRecyclerHolder to CustomRecyclerHolder. There are a lot of errors in the code. There is an error in the CustomAdaper constructor. The error says, there is no default constructor in 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter'. I tried various things, but Array adapter constructor doesn't take object:List as it's second parameter. Please help me out here

Comment: That is because I have customized it by taking it from a working app. I'll correct it.

Comment: Edited. Please have a look.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.mypc.samplesearch.ArrayAdapterSearchView.setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference. Can you please resolve this is error?

Comment: Sure .......java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.pc.samplesearch.ArrayAdapterSearchView.setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.example.pc.samplesearch.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:81)                                                searchView.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.LEFT));

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Comment: Have you stated your SearchView inside the menu like this?
app:actionViewClass="com.example.pc.samplesearch.ArrayAdapterSearchView"

Comment: It is working fine now. Thank you so much. I have a few more questions. How do I make the drop down suggestion list better? In the sense, larger text size? Also, why does the suggestion list appear on application startup? What's the code to disable the list appearing on startup?

Comment: You have to control the visibility of the drop down list via "recycleLayout" variable. When the Text Change Listener is working and only if matches are found you have to show the drop down list and otherwise hide it.

Comment: Got it. Also, can I make the suggestion list clickable? As in, when I click on Item two, the string should get populated on the search field

Comment: I think it happens already, doesn't it?
Thanks for the acceptance!
searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String length = searchView.getText();
        searchView.setSelection(length.length());
    }
});

Comment: I tried it.  Technically speaking, it should work. It isn't working.

Comment: Could you look into the issue?

Comment: Sure. Could you hold on for a second? Um working on it.

Comment: See the EDITED content inside "ExampleActivity". That will do.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect now. Also, I have an image to add to the background. How do I fit it perfectly under the search bar? A part of the image is covered by the search bar

Comment: @vidulaJ ..can you help me out here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532667/particular-titlefetched-from-api-using-searchview

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use [Material SearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView).

http://joerichard.net/android/android-material-design-searchview-example/

```
MaterialSearchView searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //Do some magic
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Do some magic
                return false;
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchViewShown() {
                //Do some magic
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewClosed() {
                //Do some magic
            }
        });
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Please check the question. He is asking for "How to implement AutoCompleteTextView within onQueryTextChange function of SearchView in actionbar" and not just SearchVIew